# Laravel Mix 2 создать 2 версии файла

Tags: webpack, pagespeed-insights, laravel-mix

В PageSpeed Insights появилась новая метрика "Не отправляйте устаревший код JavaScript в современные браузеры"

```
    …frontend/item.js?v=1.11.71
6,0 KiB
…frontend/item.js?v=1.11.71:1:190879
@babel/plugin-transform-classes
…frontend/item.js?v=1.11.71:1:524566
Number.isInteger
```

Как можно сделать в конфиге чтобы создавалось 2 версии?

Comment: 2 версии чего???

Comment: @Избыток Сусликов 2 версии обработанного вебпаком файла